# Save loaded RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView after Scroll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` inside another `RecyclerView`, the problem is that after I scroll the first `RecyclerView`, then when I return to the top, the inner `RecyclerView` is recreated and accordingly resets the scrolled position.

How to make it so that when the main `RecyclerView` is scrolled, the secondary `RecyclerView` are saved and not reset?

This is implemented in the Play market, I need to do the same.

[As it looks to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoBly.gif)

[How it looks in the Play store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvVuH.gif)

Comment: If there's not much rows, adding the RecyclerViews inside a ScrollView will save you from lots of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing the code in `onBindViewHolder()` of outer recycler view I believe this is where you must be adding the adapter to your inner RecyclerView.

Once you have added the recycler view you can save the inner recycler view's state by checking the `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` method of `LayoutManager` of inner `RecyclerView` when the inner view is done scrolling. To listen to inner RecyclerView's scrolling you must use a `addOnScrollListener()` on inner `RecyclerView`. The best place to save this state would be in the initial list you provide in your outer `RecyclerView`.

Lastly when your `onBindViewHolder()` is called just set the adapter and call `scrollToPosition()` to scroll to the last scrolled state